# True/false? The negation of "If it snows, then the train isn't on time." is "When the train is on time, then it doesn't snow."

Tags: propositional-calculus, word-problem

> True/false? The negation of "If it snows, then the train isn't on
>   time." is "When the train is on time, then it doesn't snow."

This is a confusing task, I tried to give these words variables.

So let

$$a= \text{snow}$$

$$b = \text{not on time}$$

First sentence: $a \rightarrow b$

Second sentence: $\neg b \rightarrow \neg a$

Thus the statement is false beccause $a \rightarrow b \neq b \rightarrow a $

But I'm really not sure on that : /

Comment: The negation of $a \to b$ is $a \land \lnot b$.

Comment: The second sentence is called the **contraposition** of the initial sentence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're reaching a correct conclusion, but saying "because $a\to b\neq b\to a$" doesn't work as an argument for it.

To begin with, you're just asserting this non-equality, not arguing for it -- and at the level of this exercise I think you're supposed to provide some kind of argument, such as a truth assignment for $a$ and $b$ that gives the two sides different truth values.

More seriously, it is not clear at all what $b\to a$ has to do with anything in your argument. I'm getting afraid that you think the negation of $a\to b$ should be $b\to a$ or something like that, which is not the case.

The negation of $a\to b$ is $a\land \neg b$. So negating "if it snows then the train is not on time", should be, "**it snows, and yet the train is on time**".

---

A more subtle thing here is that one should *probably* not represent the English "if -- then" as merely $\to$ in the original sentence. Representing it as just $a\to b$ implicitly makes it into a claim about *one particular time* (or *one particular possible world*), whereas the English sentence seems to express a more general judgement: "At every relevant time when it snows, it will also hold that the train is not on time". (Let's leave the ambiguity about which times are "relevant" unresolved; that's not the interesting point).

Negating the sentence *above* would also invert the implied quantifier, so we *should* end up with something like

> There **is (was, may be, will be, could be?) an occasion** when it snows and yet the train is on time.

Unfortunately, the exercise is probably meant to be one of propositional logic where this cannot even be clearly expressed, and authors/teachers are generally not much respectful of how it violates the meaning of natural-language sentences to shoehorn them into the propositional mold.

Comment: [+1] Thorough answer, but at the end, is  "time is on time" a pun ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: Sadly no, just a typo. Fixed.

Comment: @amWhy: The goal is to reassure the reader that he's not going mad if he thinks (as I think he's likely to do) that "it snows and the train is on time" sounds like a quite different claim from "it is not the case that if it snows, the train is late".

Comment: @HenningMakholm  That is fine, But more than half your post approaches a rant about how natural language can't well be formalized, which, if acknowledged in a sentence or two, would have been fine. Much of what you say in your rant is true, but not entirely relevant to this OP.  I'm not downvoting; I just think your original post was more appropriate.  That's just me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the two statements are equivalent, rather than the negation of each other! So, the statement is False.

Your symbolizations are correct, though it is better to use "the train is on time" for $b$ rather than the train is not on time ... when you have a 'not', it is better to treat that as a logical operator. So you get:

$a \rightarrow \neg b$

and

$b \rightarrow \neg a$

And they are equivalent, since they are each other's *contrapositive*. That is, when you have a conditional, you can swap the two sides, and negate both sides, and the result will be equivalent:  $P \rightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow \neg Q \rightarrow \neg P$

To see this, take a simpler example:

'if it rains, the streets are wet'

Given this, what do you know if the streets are not wet?  You know that it doesn't rain, of course! So from the above statement, you can infer:

'if the streets are not wet, it does not rain'

And it turns out you can go the other way around as well: if you know that 
'if the streets are not wet, it does not rain', and it does rain? Then the streets must be wet, since if they are not, it shouldn't be raining. So, we can go back to 'if it rains, the streets are wet'.

In other words, these two sentences are logically equivalent.

In your case, the two sentences given to you are equivalent as well by this very 'contrapositive' principle. So no, the second one is *not* the negation of the first.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**: **The highlighted statement at the top of your post is false.**

**Long answer:**

You've defined your propositions to be

(a) It snows.

(b) The train is not on time.

In $(1)$ I'll list the statement you are to negate, and its contrapositive, which is equivalent to it: $$a \to b \equiv \lnot b \to \lnot a\tag 1$$

So the negation of $a \to b$ is **not** given by $\lnot b \to \lnot a$. In fact, as I mention above, the two statements are logically equivalent.

Nor is the negation of $a\to b$ given by $\lnot a \to \lnot b \equiv b\to a$, which is the inverse of $a\to b$.

The negation of any statement $p$ is simply $\lnot p$. In this case $p=: a\to b$.

So **the negation of** $(a \to b)$ is given by $\lnot(a \to b)$:

$$\begin{align} \lnot(a \to b) &\equiv \lnot(\lnot a \lor b) \tag{implication}\\ \\
& \equiv a \land \lnot b\tag{Demorgan's}\end{align}$$